# How can I make sure load draws the correct current?

Tags: current, boost, load

[image]

I'm using the following boost converter topology to supply power to a vacuum fluorescent display. The PWM signal is 500kHz at a 80% duty cycle. I'm getting the 75V I need with some headroom to spare. My question is:
**How would I go about ensuring that the load resistance is sufficiently high enough so that I don't draw too much current from the boost converter?**

Is it as simple as just slapping on an extra current limiting resistor?

Thank you

Comment: The load takes whatever current it needs at the voltage you give to it. And your supply must be able to provide the current amd the voltage the load needs. So it depends what kind of load your VFD is and the data sheet would tell that. If you have a VFD module with a driver chip, it likely has onboard resistors. If you have a bare glass you need to drive yourself, it would make sense to have current limiting resistors. Which VFD you have?

Comment: It's a GP1247AI. For the anode driver current it's asking for about 40mA. The datasheet doesn't have any electrical characterstics aside from the voltage and current ratings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I'll point out is that finding a 1 mH inductor that has decent performance at a switching rate of 500 kHz could be troublesome but, assuming you have one, your duty cycle will be theoretically about 84% with the circuit you show and, you could raise the load resistor value (currently 750 Ω) considerably higher without upsetting the stable output voltage.

In other words, your converter is operating in CCM with 750 Ω load and, will only drop into DCM when that load resistor rises to around 46.6 kΩ. In DCM the output voltage will rise for a fixed duty cycle so, this is to be avoided.

> *How would I go about ensuring that the load resistance is sufficiently
> high enough so that I don't draw too much current from the boost
> converter?*

I assume you mean that you want a resistor in parallel with the real load so that when the real load (750 Ω) is disconnected, the output voltage is still stable at 75 volts.

20 kΩ would be my suggestion (if I read your question correctly).

If you then realized that finding a 1 mH inductor that had good efficiency at a 500 kHz switching rate might be problematic, you might decide something much lower is acceptable. With a 100 μH inductor, the transition to DCM happens when the load resistor is 4.66 kΩ (theoretical). But, you get a 1.2 watt inherent power dissipation in that resistor.

Of course, you could bite the bullet and use a control loop to set the duty cycle and this means you could enter DCM (on light loads) and still maintain the 75 volt output. Maybe that's a step too-far for you?

Comment: I've considered using a control loop, but I figured it would be unnecessary given that the load would be relatively constant. As far as my boost converter design, I just picked values of components that I've had on hand and that would meet my desired voltage, I didn't really factor in efficiency into my design. Do you have any resources that you would recommend for studying power circuit design? I'm in school for EE right now, and we've only touched on the basic boost converter topology. Given your explanation, I realize I need more knowledge to practically implement something

Comment: @MXVG sorry I don't have any resources that I can think of. Nothing is springing to mind. Or, put another way; I just don't use resources any more i.e. I haven't read a text book since (I guess) the 1980s. There is a book (or several) by a guy called Christophe Basso that covers the whole gamut of switching converters. He appears on this site every day or so hence, I've heard of him and a lot of folk who come here respect his knowledge/books as far as I can tell. I can't give you his alias because he's kind-of incognito but, take a look at his books. He does on-line presentations too.